# Run cmd bat file in PHP

Tags: php, batch-file, codeigniter-3

I am trying to run a .bat file from PHP in a WAMP server on Windows. Below is my code, the first "if" statement runs and prints "Successful" to the screen. So, the function "exec" is running, but no file has been copied. Any help or advice please.

```
// Function run bat file
private function run_bat(){

    $path = 'wamp\www\application\common\get_file.bat';
    $batchCmd = "C:\\".$path;
    echo "<br>".$batchCmd;
    //if(exec('cmd /c '.$batchCmd)){
    if(exec($batchCmd)){
        echo '<br>Successful';
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        echo '<br>Error in run bat';
        return FALSE;
    }
} // end function run bat file
```

my bat file just copies one file to a new folder. The other file is on a networked drive.

Comment: `my bat file just copies one file to a new folder.` PHP can do that as well using the copy function.

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt sometimes, a simple command is just for a testing purpose to minimal other issue, it does help to see how the foundation mechanism to work. For PHP calling a Windows batch file to success is not as simple as u may thought.

Answer (score 0):

To run a bat script, you should use `cmd /c filename`. So you have to change the code to something like this

```
$batchCmd = "cmd /c C:\\" . $path;
```

Comment: with "$batchCmd = "cmd /c C:\\" . $path;" all I am getting is the same, Successful but no copied files. Does the bat need to be in the same folder as the php script?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably run it like this

```
system("cmd /c C: path_to_your_file");
```

in your case

```
system("cmd /c  $batchCmd ");
```

or go for

```
exec("c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c START  $batchCmd" );
```

Comment: with "exec("c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c START  $batchCmd" )" the window just says "waiting for localhost" and never comes back up.

Comment: Did you try it with simple quote exec('c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c START $batchCmd' )

Comment: let me ask a stupid question did you bat file works without php?

Comment: yes, it runs without PHP, simple quotes it just runs and runs "waiting for localhost"

Comment: i would suggest changed your server name from localhost to 127.0.0.1 in database connection configuration. It seems that is a well known issue. Hope it will help