# Running a .bat file from php which is hosted on a wamp server

Tags: php, html, batch-file, wamp

This is the code I wrote which helps me upload an image from a html page`(https://pastebin.com/hjDYrXs0 saved as index.html.php)` that I've hosted locally using wamp server :

```
 
    $upload_dir = 'uploads'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $allowed_types = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gif');
    $maxsize = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
    if(!empty(array_filter($_FILES['files']['name']))) {
 
        foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $value) {
            
            $file_tmpname = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
            $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
            $file_ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 
 
            $filepath = $upload_dir.$file_name;
 
            if(in_array(strtolower($file_ext), $allowed_types)) {
 
                if ($file_size > $maxsize)      
                    echo "Error: File size is larger than the allowed limit.";
                if(file_exists($filepath)) {
                    $filepath = $upload_dir.time().$file_name;
                    
                    if( move_uploaded_file($file_tmpname, $filepath)) {
                        echo "{$file_name} successfully uploaded <br />";
                ..... other conditions (not uploaded and not selected)........
```

So basically I want to send the image I get from the uploaded php as an argument to the batch file like `A:\WAMP\www\test\uploads\batscript.bat A:\WAMP\www\test\uploads\upload.jpg`
It works if I execute it manually.

After going through other similar questions over here at stack like
[Run cmd bat file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47292826/run-cmd-bat-file-in-php) ,
[How do you run a .bat file from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835941/how-do-you-run-a-bat-file-from-php) , [How to execute batch file via PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088379/how-to-execute-batch-file-via-php/19088504)

I tried these things

```
echo system("cmd /c  A:\WAMP\www\test\uploads\batscript.bat $file_name");
echo exec("A:\WAMP\www\test\uploads\batscript.bat $file_name");
```

Unfortunately it isn't working....
Any clues to what I could do to make it work ? ? ?

Comment: [Never post links to or images of code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: @RiggsFolly alright ! I'll paste the php code snippets

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've edited it .